# msgpack python custom objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, msgpack

I am communicating with another system which uses msgpack.
Have been trying to pack and unpack custom objects using msgpack python package. But haven't managed to do it properly.

The messages which are arrays, are structured like this:

```py
[Header, Payload]
```

here defined in a class that I call `Message`.

Header is an array of length two integers `[number, type]`.
`Payload` however is a map with integer keys. Inside `Payload` there are also maps with integers keys.
So I can have a payload that looks like this:

```py
{ 
  7: {8: 0.1}, 
  1: {1: 1.3}
}
```

I have written a method to encode such a message

```py
def encode(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Message):
        return [obj.header, obj.payload]
    elif isinstance(obj, Header):
        return [obj.number, obj.type]
    elif isinstance(obj, Payload):
        return obj.data

    raise ValueError(f"Wrong input for message. This object is given {obj}")
```

where Payload is defined as a class with a dictionary:

```py
class Payload:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.data = {}
```

I am able to encode the message with

```py
message = Message()
packed = msgpack.packb(message, default=encode)
```

But I am unable to decode it using `msgpack.unpackb`. Based on the short documentation I decode like this

```py
unpacked = msgpack.unpackb(packed, object_hook=decode, strict_map_key=False)
```

What I don't know is how I can write the decode method properly.
If I define a `decode` function like this:

```py
def decode(packed_obj):
    print(f'decode called with {packed_obj}')
```

I get this output

```
decode called with {8: 0.1}
decode called with {1: 1.3}
decode called with {1: None, 7: None}
```

It seems that msgpack starts by calling the method for the deepest dictionaries and then works its way up.
But I am struggling how I can reconstruct an object of `Payload`.

I thought I could go through the valid keys and if the value is a float, then I know this is the inner dict. But the decode function should eventually return an object of the class `Message`.

I am using python 3.6 and msgpack 1.0.0 which is installed with pip.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving an answer here in case anyone gets to this later.
The solution is to separate the unpacking from decoding.
The primitive types are automatically unpacked without the need for a special decode function.

So in the example, this dictionary can be directly encoded & decoded:

```py
{ 
  7: {8: 0.1}, 
  1: {1: 1.3}
}
```

What you need is simply calling `unpackb` without an object hook function.

```py
unpacked = msgpack.unpackb(packed, strict_map_key=False)
```

You can then write a function to decode that gets this ditionary and decodes it.